# Negative Document Count in a Document Library, now what?

Tags: document-library

I have something strange: I have a document library with a negative document count.

When browsing to the document library it seems to be empty, when I put one document in it, the number increases (from -33 to -32) and when I delete it, it drops one again.

[image: Negative document count]

What may have triggered this behaviour?

How can I force a recalculation?

And does this mean all my document counts may be off (with no way to tell, except counting the documents by hand)?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that you are experiencing a "common" bug in the item count logic. I wasn't yet able to find anything concrete about what triggers this bug, but I can confirm that you aren't the only one with a negative document count for a library/list.

I will keep searching, but it seems that no solution was provided by Microsoft at the moment. Atlas, [this blog post](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/negative-item-count-in-document-libraries/) describe your issue and provide a workaround that would force a recalc of the item count. Basically you would force a serie of "fake" document copy and deletion to resync the item count - I never had to use it, but it could be worty a try (don't know HOW it would work if versioning is enabled).

Will update if I find out something more specific.